# Tenia que crear un arreglo, indicar si existe el numero ingresado eso ya lo hice, me falta borrar las repeticiones que haya del numero en el arreglo

Tags: java, array

1)Hace falta eliminar las repeticiones del numero que se ingreso por teclado pero solo las repeticiones no el numero tambien esta fue mi falla ya que me borra el numero y las repeticiones y aparte me duplica el ultimo numero del arreglo, ayuda porfavor
2)Necesito hacer en C# tambien

Aqui dejo la tarea:
Crear una aplicación que me cree un arreglo unidimensional y lo llene con números aleatorios
del 1 al 100. Luego ingrese un número y me indique si este existe en el arreglo y me elimine
todas sus repeticiones.

```
    public static int ExistenciaPosicion(int[] arreglo, int numero) 
    {
       for (int i = 0; i < arreglo.length; i++) 
       {
           if (arreglo[i] == numero) 
           {
           return i;
           }
       }
     return -1;
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        
        Scanner teclado = new Scanner(System.in);
        int tamaño = 10;
        int numero = 0;
        int numeros [] = new int [tamaño];
        
        System.out.print("El arreglo es: " );
        for (int i = 0; i < numeros.length; i++) 
        {
            //si multiplicamos por 100 tenemos 0-99 entonces sumamos uno y da de 1-100
            
            numeros[i]  = (int)(Math.random()*100+1);
            System.out.print(+numeros[i] +"  ");
        }
        System.out.println(" ");
        
        System.out.print("Ingrese el numero que quiere encontrar: ");
        
        numero = teclado.nextInt();
        
        int PosicionNumeroBuscado = ExistenciaPosicion(numeros, numero);
     
        if (PosicionNumeroBuscado == -1) 
           {
            System.out.println("El numero no existe en el arreglo");
           } 
        else 
        {
           
           System.out.println("El numero si existe en el arreglo");
          
           
           for (int i = 0; i < numeros.length; i++)
            {
               if (numeros[i] == numero)
                   {
                     
                     for (int m = i; m < numeros.length-1; m++)
                     {
                        numeros[m] = numeros[m+1];
                     }
                   }
            }
           
           }
            System.out.print("El arreglo quedaria: ");
            
            for (int n = 0; n < numeros.length; n++) 
            {
                System.out.print(numeros[n] +"  ");

            }
            System.out.println();
            
//            
          }
       }
```

Comment: Bienvenido a [es.so]. Te invito a leer [ask] y a realizar el [tour]. Las preguntas que piden que otros hagan los deberes por ti terminan cerradas. Debes mostrar un [mre] de lo que has intentado por tu cuenta para resolver el problema, explicando dónde tienes fallas o errores. Mucho me temo que tu pregunta termine cerrada. Saludos

Comment: Muchas gracias si eso hice ahi esta mi codigo como verificación

Comment: Tu código solo muestra lo que ya has resuelto y tu pregunta se basa en lo que te falta por responder.

Comment: Ya lo subi completo gracias, era para no confundir que no subi la parte que estaba equivocada, pero ya la puse

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Podrías modificar tu método `ExistenciaPosicion` para que de manera practica te retorne las ocurrencias de un numero en un arreglo

```
public static int ocurrencias(int []arreglo,int numero){
  int cont=0;
   for (int i=0;i<arreglo.length;i++) {
      if(arreglo[i]==numero){
            cont++;
      }
   }return cont;

}
```

Al regresar `0` se entenderá que  el numero no existe dentro del arreglo

```
int posicionNumeroBuscado = ocurrencias(numeros, numero);

        if (posicionNumeroBuscado == 0) {
            System.out.println("El numero no existe en el arreglo");
           } 
        else {
           System.out.println("El numero si existe en el arreglo");
         }
```

Lo siguiente seria obtener el total de ocurrencias del numero buscado y eso para declarar un nuevo array donde guardar los valores según las especificaciones(borrar las repeticiones del numero buscado)

```
int ocurrenciasNumeroBuscado=ocurrencias(numeros,numero);
int []newArray=new int[numeros.length-ocurrenciasNumeroBuscado+1];
```

el nuevo array sera del tamaño del array original - las ocurrencias del numero buscado + 1(el numero buscado)

```
           int j=0;
           int k=0;
           for (int i=0;i<numeros.length;i++ ) {
            //guardamos los numeros diferentes al numero buscado
               if(numeros[i]!=numero){
                   newArray[j]=numeros[i];
                   j++;
            //guardamos por unica vez el numero buscado
               }else if(numeros[i]==numero && k==0){
                   newArray[j]=numeros[i];
                   j++;
                   k++;
               }
           }
```

Comment: Muchisimas gracias

Comment: @Estudiante si te sirvió la respuesta dale check-in ✓ ,saludos